# imageView.getLeft(), imageView.getLeft() result 0 use array

Tags: android

i dont know whats wrong with my imageView after i declaration with array, result 0

```
        imageViewTarget = new ImageView[] {
            (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewTarget1),
            (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewTarget2),
            (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewTarget3),
            (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewTarget4),
            (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewTarget5),
            (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewTarget6),
            (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewTarget7),
            (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewTarget8) };

    for (int i = 0; i < imageViewTarget.length; i++) {

        System.out.println("Left : "
                + imageViewTarget[i].getLeft() + " Right : "
                + imageViewTarget[i].getRight());
    }
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just now created the view so the View default values are set to be ZERO..after View attached to the window You will get the correct values..try get the values like this in `onWindowFocusChanged()` method..

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    System.out.println(button.getLeft());
    System.out.println(button.getRight());
}
```

Comment: its working, but get error if i save value to array..
  for (int i = 0; i < imageViewTarget.length; i++) {
    targetLeft[i] = imageViewTarget[i].getLeft();
   targetRight[i] = imageViewTarget[i].getRight();
  }

Comment: i wanna create game tetravex, drag and drop use imageView with array..

you can see source code here  http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=uRupGmgQ

sorry if my english not good.. hehehe...

Comment: From your code it is NullPointerException..you are not initialized some values like..targetLeft[],targetRigth[] and two more initialize it in your onCreate() method..

Comment: @kaylan pv: still not working, imageView.length = 8, result is

Left : 18 Right : 140
Left : 18 Right : 140
Left : 18 Right : 140
Left : 18 Right : 140
Left : 18 Right : 140
Left : 18 Right : 140
Left : 111 Right : 233
Left : 111 Right : 233
Left : 111 Right : 233
Left : 111 Right : 233
Left : 202 Right : 324
Left : 202 Right : 324
Left : 204 Right : 326
Left : 204 Right : 326
Left : 205 Right : 327
Left : 205 Right : 327

Answer (score 0):

```
getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

        // all views has been placed
        // make your calculation now...
    }
});
```

@kaylan pvs: `onWindowFocusChanged` is not a reliable way of solving the problem. It may be called multiple times and there is no guarantee that all the views has been placed when `onWindowFocusChanged` is triggered.

Comment: how can i use this way, if i wanna save value on array?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you are trying to pull view values directly from the view in the onCreate(), which is not the point in which views generate their view properties. They generate their properties in the onResume() if my memory serves me.